# Closing fancybox window: works on iframe but not on ajax

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a working fancybox modal window with the next code:

```
        $("a#add-project").click(function(){
            $.fancybox({
                type: 'ajax',
                href: BASEPATH + 'time/addProject',
                fitToView: false,
                autoSize: false,
                width: 500,
                height: 300,
                closeClick: false,
                openEffect: 'none',
                closeEffect: 'none',
                beforeClose: function() {
                    console.log('closed');
                }
            });
        });
```

That AJAX window contains a button with the next code:

```
    $('#addproject-close').bind("click keypress", function(){
        $.fancybox.close(true); 
        $.fancybox.close();
        parent.$.fancybox.close(true);
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
        console.log('tried to close');
    });
```

I know that it works because I see the **tried to close** message on console but there is NO way to close that window. I tried with all the possible things but nothing. In the past I had this window with type: 'iframe' and with parent.$... just worked.

How I can do it in ajax?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you create some jsfiddle for it?

Comment: @AmarPalsapure how I can "recreate" the AJAX call in jsfiddle? thank you

Comment: You can read this http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside your AJAX window, create your closing button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close();" id="addproject-close">close fancybox</a>
```

... and forget about the `.bind()` method.

That should do the trick. [See demo](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/closeFromAjax_16feb12.html)